# How do I remove the blue square that appears when I click the button on small screens?

Tags: html, css, button, click, outline

When I set the screen size to be small in Chrome dev tools or when I check my project on my phone, a blue square temporarily appears around the button when I click it. I have tried to set `outline: none` or `outline: 0` to `button`, `button:hover`, `button:focus` and `button:active` to prevent this, but there was no visible change. I checked the styling in Chrome dev tools, but I can't figure out where this blue square comes from and how to remove it or make it invisible. Any help is welcome.

This is my HTML:

```
<button>
    <span class="dice-wrapper">
        <img src="./src/assets/icon-dice.svg" alt="Dice icon">
    </span>
</button>
```

This is my CSS:

```
button {
  width: 64px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--neon-green);
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 3px var(--neon-green);
}

button:focus, button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Full code on GitHub: https://github.com/Marjolein-Kasman-de-Jong/advice-generator-app

Project on GitHub Pages: https://marjolein-kasman-de-jong.github.io/advice-generator-app/

Comment: This is an `outline`, applied via the `:focus-visible` pseudo class.

Comment: I just learned about the existence of this pseudo class. ;-) I will read up on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work! I didn't know this property existed. I will study it some more, but this may very well be the solution to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: MDN can help you:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color @Marjolein

Comment: You are being very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

See [this Mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) for information about the `:focus-visible` pseudo class.

To save you a few clicks, try:

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

or

```
button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Also try removing a box shadow (`box-shadow: none;`).

Please note that

#### This isn't good practice

as screen reader users will not be able to see their pointer. Check [here](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-25-never-remove-css-outlines/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20CSS%20rule%20%3Afocus,with%20the%20link%20or%20control) for more info.